# Select unique .mp3 files in a set of backups. Mac, Unix

Tags: macos, unix, mp3, file-listing

I am currently reorganizing all my backups. I have the problem that in those various backups there are both different and same .mp3 files.

I was wondering if there is a program or code for mac which can search for all the .mp3 files in a map and it's underlying maps/directory's. And if possible the program also copy unique versions of those .mp3 files to another directory.

With kind regards,
Bigsortvids

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of time searching on google and other forums and by trying I have found the following command as an answer:

```
find /fromWhichDirectory "*.mp3" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv "{}" /toWhichDirectory
```

!!!! PAY ATTENTION that when you don't end the command with ctrl+c and you delete the files that where moved or copied to the toWhichDirectory terminal will try to replace the files with the files from fromWhichDirectory which in the case of moving(mv) you get irritating errors and in the case of copying(cp) all the files will be copied again.

I just wanted to delete some(3000) .mp3 files that didn't fit in the row and they just appeared again. Very irritating and long process, took me an hour to delete all the right mp3 files and empty the trashcan. I had to remove almost 100gb of mp3 );

Hope I helped someone with this answer,
greetings,
Bigsortvids

Comment: Well done for finding an answer to your question then posting the answer, with shortfalls for others.

Comment: Another approach perhaps was to do a search, recursively, for all .mp3 files, and put the results, pathway and file name, in a list doc. Then order list by file name, then use unique to determine a list of unique .mp3 file names. Then use that list of files with pathways to copy to your new drive a unique set.  One would need to know how to use the various unix commands, incl likely awk, well. At this point since I have not had time to confirm the details and test it works, hence will not post as an answer.  Offered more as alternate solution for you to consider.

Comment: The above would only work to keep a unique copy of all .mp3 files if the name of any .mp3 files has not been altered. If it has been altered, you may still get some duplicate mp3 files, with the altered different file names.

Comment: Someone else may yet post a more elegant solution.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to clarify your question, as often happens on here. Do check I have not changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: Thank you @Cam_Aust for all your help, I just checked out the unique command and it indeed seems very usefull in my case, because I got many mp3 with altered names but which represent the same number.

Comment: No problem. Have taken the time as you seem a relative newcomer to Stackoverflow. I recall the experience myself and I like to encourage others. Hope you go on to grow in SO. I may come back and delete some of these comments.

Comment: Also note use of code block.  It is triggered by four leading spaces.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @Cam_Aust!